# Unable to match Pattern

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a long string to text that I have to regex to find just one short string of text.

For example, I have to get the website content from http://www.hltv.org/match/2290951-uumlberholverbot-legendbots-bot-tournament-2014. After getting the content, I just need to match a string in the website's source, where `this.content` is the retrieved website's source and I need to match `date:"1396706400000", htmlTemplate:`.

The regex works well, just that it always returns error.

```
public String getCountdown() {
        Pattern countdownPattern = Pattern.compile("date:\"(.*?)\", htmlTemplate");
        Matcher m = countdownPattern.matcher(this.content);
        if (m.find()) {
            String time = m.group(1).trim();
            return time;
        } else {
            return "ERROR";
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Works fine: http://regex101.com/r/zJ0wA0

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is fine.  There is something else wrong with your code, or the input data is not what you think it is.

One slight tweak I would suggest to the pattern is:

```
"date:\"[^\"]+\", htmlTemplate"
```

This would be a more robust way of matching.  But your problem is not with the matching pattern.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with the code (no offense). Right before I use the pattern matcher, I printed out the content onto the logs window and it shows the website's source correctly. I'm not sure why it just doesn't match :/

Comment: @user2301818, but *something* must be wrong, and it is not the regular expression--multiple users have tested that, and it works.  By process of elimination is almost certainly something else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code is working fine, I did the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String content;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.hltv.org/match/2290951-uumlberholverbot-legendbots-bot-tournament-2014");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                content = inputStreamToString(is);
                final TextView message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        message.setText(getCountdown());
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public String getCountdown() {
    Pattern countdownPattern = Pattern.compile("date:\"(.*?)\", htmlTemplate");
    Matcher m = countdownPattern.matcher(this.content);
    if (m.find()) {
        String time = m.group(1).trim();
        return time;
    } else {
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:id="@+id/message" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Only trap is the *lovely* java way to convert a `HttpResponse` to a simple `String`. Is there a better / simpler way to do?